# How does roles work in Keyrock?

Tags: authorization, roles, fiware, role-base-authorization, fiware-keyrock

I want to know how the role based authorization works in FIWARE Keyrock. I have tested a scenario where a user A registers an application appA in Keyrock. The user B that is not on the authorized list for application appA can request a token for another application (appB, for example) and successfully access the appA with the token obtained from appB.

Another test performed was to include user A in the authorized list for appA, but with a role that has no permissions. Again, the user A gets access to appA with credentials from another application.

Can anyone explain me how this work, if it really work?

Comment: I recommend you to take a look to the GE courses. There you will find a working example of that configuration

Comment: https://edu.fiware.org/course/view.php?id=131

Comment: Thanks. I had ignored the exact part of permission configuration at Keyrock previously, some months ago, because it was not of my interest. Now, I am interested in this functionality and I had forgot that this video presents such information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Álvaro said in comments, we can see an example of this configuration at [this video](https://edu.fiware.org/mod/url/view.php?id=735).

When I saw this video, previously, I had ignored the exact part of permission configuration at Keyrock, because it was not of my interest. Now, I am interested in this functionality and I had forgot that this video presents such information.

Besides, below I put what I had to do for things work:

Install AZF:

- sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk (if you dont have)
- sudo apt-get install tomcat7
- wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/authzforce/authzforce-ce-server-dist/5.4.1/authzforce-ce-server-dist-5.4.1.deb (authzforce)
- sudo apt-get install gdebi curl
- sudo gdebi authzforce-ce-server-dist-5.4.1.deb

Configure Wilma PEP (`config.js` file):

```
config.azf = {
        enabled: true,
        protocol: 'http',
        host: '10.30.0.21', //this is your authzforce ip
        port: 8080, //6019,
        custom_policy: undefined // use undefined to default policy checks (HTTP verb + path).
};
```

Configure Keyrock (`local_settings.py` file, located in `/horizon/openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py`)

```
ACCESS_CONTROL_URL = 'http://10.30.0.21:8080'
ACCESS_CONTROL_MAGIC_KEY = None # If you have problems, put something instead of None. Currently there is a reported bug related to this.
```

Remember to restart the services. To let the things work, you need to create the specific permission to the right endpoint of the application you want to secure/access. Once it is created, the AZF will be consulted by the Wilma PEP Proxy.

I hope it helps someone.